# How can i place the "Categories", right next to the "Comments" icon? Details below

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress website.

URL: http://sideboxx.com/)

Issue: Please check this (Screenshot: http://prnt.sc/drao47)

I want to place a single category, right next to the comment icon in blog posts on the homepage.

This can't be done with CSS, Right?

I've tried looking into my theme files and I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it below two way..**

1. For change the position of category, You just need to change HTML content from core HTML file.
2. Using CSS

Answer (score 0):

For only categories names in post you have to place this code.

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ',') ); 
    //'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.' 
 ?>
```

place this code in while loop where you want to show .
using **CSS you can align this category name where you want.**

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme folder open file blog.php in notepad and search for `<div class="post-footer">`.

**Probably it found inside a blog.php file but if not then search for whole theme directory.**

```
<div class="post-footer">
 <!-- add new div here-->
<span> <?php echo get_the_category( $post_id); ?></span>
</div>
```

Save file and check output.That's it.